# Find the number of times and length of time where n or more intervals overlap

Tags: algorithm

Given a list of number intervals e.g.:

```
[
[1,5],
[3,7],
[4,10],
[8,17],
[11,13],
[13,19]
]
```

Find the number of times n or more intervals overlap and how long the total intervals are. For example, if `n = 3`, there would be two overlaps (`[1,5], [3,7], [4,10]` and `[8,17], [11,13], [13,19]`). The first overlap occurs over `[4,5]` and the second overlap occurs over `[13,13]` so the *total length of overlap* is `(5 - 4) + (13 - 13) == 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split each interval into `begin` and `end` and sort them; make a decision what to do if intervals touch one another (interval starts exactly when other interval ends). In your case, if positions are equal, we should assume `begin < end`, `(x, begin) < (x, end)` for all `x`.

```
( 1, begin)
( 3, begin)
( 4, begin)
( 5, end)
( 7, end)
( 8, begin)
(10, end)
(11, begin)
(13, begin) # note, that 'begin' should be first
(13, end)   # note, that 'end' should be last
(17, end)
(19, end)
```

Then loop over this collection adding `1` for `begin` and subtract 1 for `end` to the intersection:

Pseudocode:

```
int intersections = 0;
int start = -1;

int times = 0;
int totalLength = 0;

foreach ((int at, bool isBegin) in collection) {
  if (isBegin) {
    intersections += 1;

    if (intersections == n) {
      times += 1;
      start = at;
    }
  }
  else {
    intersections -= 1;

    if (intersections == n - 1) 
      totalLength += at - start;
  } 
}

WriteLine($"{times} intervals with {totalLength} length in total");
```

Time complexity: `O(m * log(m))`, space complexity: `O(m)` where `m` is a number of given intervals